# How to convert these two unmanaged structures to managed types?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

The first one in my c++ namespace is

```
      public struct channel_vars {
      int fetch_data;    /* Boolean flag */
      void * data;       /* (malloc'd) address of data */
      unsigned int lines;    /* Number of lines returned */
}
```

I don't know what the void* is supposed to turn into when managed

The second one is

```
public struct hdf_call_vars_t {
 struct channel_vars p_vars;
   struct channel_vars s_vars; 
  enum FILE_VERSION file_vers;   /* Set in top level sub. used in lower */
  int fetch_n;    /* Boolean flag */
  s_line_header_t * n_addr; /* malloc'd address of ndata */
  unsigned int n_lines;
  csdt_file_header_t hdr;   
};
```

In the one above, s_line_header_t is itself a struct which is made up of doubles and ints and another structure that is also made up of basic types like ints etc.

Since managed code doesn't allow pointers, how do I convert these structures to managed types? All this code is in my c++ -cli project.
thanks,
sb

Comment: Do you want to convert them to managed C++, or do you want to be able to use them from C#? Or both.

Comment: Also, we need more info to help. They look like they will be used by unmanaged code. And managed code does allow pointers. You should really read more about the differences between managed and unmanaged code.

Comment: thank you both. Didn't have luck with intptr, and yes, they will be used by unmanaged code. This means I'll have to convert all the unmanaged code to managed, doesn't it? oh no! I am so not equipped with the background to accomplish that! The intptr method I used in my c# driver said that my c++ dll was looking for a pointer to the a certainb structure. Didn't want to compile if I passed in an intptr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntPtr class in managed code to map your field that uses pointer on unmaged code

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving to c# All classes are functionally identical to pointers. They operate almost in the same way in that they can either point to a class or be `null`.

`void*` is a bit more tricky. This can point to anything. In c# all objects inherit from the base `object` class. So replace all `void*` with `object` and you should be fine, since you will need a cast to get back out of a both a void* and an object.

```
public struct ChannelVars {
      public bool FetchData; 
      public object Data;   
      public uint Lines;    
}

public struct HDFCallVarsT {
      public ChannelVars PVars;
      public ChannelVars SVars; 
      //enum FILE_VERSION file_vers;  //you will need to get the enum set here correctly
      public bool FetchN;
      public SLineHeaderT NAddr; //SLineHeaderT must be a class somewhere
      public uint NLines;
      public CSDTFileHeaderT HDR; //CSDTFileHeaderT must be a class somewhere   
};
```

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend against using `object` for `void *`. You should use `IntPtr`.

Comment: He wanted a managed version of that. Its really the only similitude. The ideal solution would be to use generics OR use a base class of known possible classes that could be used.

Comment: Well, what the OP wants isn't a C# version of his C++ struct (I answered one of his previous questions earlier this day), but rather something along the lines of a managed C++/CLI struct. I personally think that he is a bit confused when it comes to managed/unmanaged code and managed/unmanaged interop. The question is, admittedly, really vague though.

Comment: Sorry I'm so vague, folks. Antonin, yes I need to convert the pointer-riddled code to managed c++. But you have stated managed c++ allows pointers. What's a good speedy book to read? Thank you so much, Ohmusama, for your detailed answer though I didn't make myself clear . And again,sorry for the vagueness.